# JQuery animating div after loading new image

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I've sussed out most of the code, but something (small I know) is eluding me:

I'm loading larger images into a div and resizing that div to match the new larger image dimensions. The div is faded in on thumbnail click, faded out on click, and changes to new resized content on clicking a new thumbnail (I'll add forward and back buttons later.)

Everything works fine, except for the animation when the div resizes. I can't see the error in my code. Any help?

HTML code:

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="small"><img src="images/small/001.jpg" width="100" height="125"><img     src="images/small/002.jpg" width="100" height="125"></div>
<div id="large"><img src="" /></div>
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#small img').click(function() {
        var image = $(this);
        var src = image.attr('src');
        src = src.split('/');
        var filename = src[src.length-1];
        var image_folder = 'images/large/';
        var large_image = $('#large img');
        large_image.attr('src', image_folder + filename);
        new_height = $('#large img').height+"px";
        new_width = $('#large img').width+"px";
        $('#large').html('');
        $('#large').append(large_image);
        if( $('#large').is(":visible") ) {
            $('#large').animate({
                "height":new_height,
                "width":new_width
            }, {duration: 1000})
        } else {
            $('#large').css('visibility','visible').hide();
            $('#large').fadeIn(1000);
        }   
    });
    $('#large').click(function(){
        $('#large').fadeOut(1000);
        //$('#large').hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: Sorry, should have added: The div resizes on clicking a new thumbnail, and to the proper dimensions. The animation, however, doesn't run; it just immediately resizes.

Answer (score 1):

I've noticed you used width and height instead of width() and height() so give it a shot to see if helps. use this one.

```
new_height = $('#large img').height()+"px";
new_width = $('#large img').width()+"px";
```

EDIT: ----------------

I'm not sure what kind of effect are your trying to apply but I've used jQuery UI and came up with this http://jsfiddle.net/v3YkY/. If you decided to use this, dont forget to add jQuery UI CSS to your page.

Comment: Hi Jay and Lix, thanks for both answers... unfortunately neither worked (though yes, I missed the ; Lix. Nice). I tried to set up a jsfiddle, but the links seem to be boggling me... source code and images (working) at seanmurphy.co.cc/trapdoor/lightbox-test1.html Again, it all works... just missing that freaking animation on the resize from one image to another. I KNOW it's just a small thing... just missing it.

Comment: @SeanMurphy, I just edited my answer. Please let me know if it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is your problem... But this line of code contradicts itself -

```
$('#large').css('visibility','visible').hide();
```

You are setting the `visibility` css parameter to `visible` and then immediately hiding the element.

You can simply use the `.show()` and `.hide()` functions without having to deal with `.css('visibility','visible')`.  The `:visible` attribute is insinuated by other attributes known to jQuery - `display` for example.

Also you are missing a semicolon after you call the `.animate()` function.  Might not be an issue now but it will definitely come up when you start testing it on different browsers.  <sub>Not mentioning any names...</sub>

Comment: Should have included the css. The div is set to display:none; To get around the firefox bug, I test for visibility, and then set the display to hide to activate the fadeIn animations. Works like a charm (and glad I found it). Good catch, though. The fadeIn's and outs are just fine; it's just the height and width animations that aren't functioning.